# the MarkerClusterer doesn't display in my map

Tags: markerclusterer

after asking about this problem of the markers clustering , me and my friends , but we dont find any solution of our problem.
obviously because we dont provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that demonstrates my issue.
so after lerning how i can provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable exemple , i asking you again about this problem who unfortunately i'm in 2 weeks.

the problem is that : I am trying to use MarkerClusterer to cluster together my points on a Google map. For some reason the map works but just shows individual markers and does not cluster them and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't work in the snippet because of this javascript error: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your `MarkerClusterer` before the markersArray is populated.

Simplest solution, create a global `markerCluster` when you initialize the map, then populate it with each marker as it is created in the `createMarker` function.

```
function createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NumAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm, OpenAmVen, CloseAmVen, OpenPmVen, ClosePmVen, OpenAmDim, CloseAmDim, OpenPmDim, ClosePmDim, IMEI, Date_Added) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title: CodeClient
  });

  markerArray.push(marker); //push local var marker into global array
  // add marker to the MarkerClusterer
  markerCluster.addMarker(marker);
// ....
```

**working code snippet:**

```js
// necessary variables
var map;
var infoWindow;
var markersData = [];
var markerCluster;
var markerArray = []; //create a global array to store markers

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32, -6),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // create MarkerClusterer, markersArray is not populated yet
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });

  // a new Info Window is created
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });
  // Finally displayMarkers() function is called to begin the markers creation
  displayMarkers();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


// This function will iterate over markersData array
// creating markers with createMarker function
function displayMarkers() {

  // this variable sets the map bounds according to markers position
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // for loop traverses markersData array calling createMarker function for each marker 
  $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abdelhakimsalama/358669eda44d8d221bf58c629402c40b/raw/bae93c852669a35f0e7053e9f8d068841ddf146a/get_data_google_api", function(response) {
    markersData = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].Latitude, markersData[i].Longitude);
      var Route = markersData[i].Route;
      var Secteur = markersData[i].Secteur;
      var Agence = markersData[i].Agence;
      var CodeClient = markersData[i].CodeClient;
      var PrecisionGPS = markersData[i].PrecisionGPS;
      var Latitude = markersData[i].Latitude;
      var Longitude = markersData[i].Longitude;
      var BarCode = markersData[i].BarCode;
      var PrenomClient = markersData[i].PrenomClient;
      var NumAdresse = markersData[i].NumAdresse;
      var Tel = markersData[i].Tel;
      var Whatsapp = markersData[i].Whatsapp;
      var NbrFrigo = markersData[i].NbrFrigo;
      var OpenAm = markersData[i].OpenAm;
      var CloseAm = markersData[i].CloseAm;
      var OpenPm = markersData[i].OpenPm;
      var ClosePm = markersData[i].ClosePm;
      var OpenAmVen = markersData[i].OpenAmVen;
      var CloseAmVen = markersData[i].CloseAmVen;
      var OpenPmVen = markersData[i].OpenPmVen;
      var ClosePmVen = markersData[i].ClosePmVen;
      var OpenAmDim = markersData[i].OpenAmDim;
      var CloseAmDim = markersData[i].CloseAmDim;
      var OpenPmDim = markersData[i].OpenPmDim;
      var ClosePmDim = markersData[i].ClosePmDim;
      var IMEI = markersData[i].IMEI;
      var Date_Added = markersData[i].Date_Added;

      createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NumAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm, OpenAmVen, CloseAmVen, OpenPmVen, ClosePmVen, OpenAmDim, CloseAmDim, OpenPmDim, ClosePmDim, IMEI, Date_Added);

      // marker position is added to bounds variable
      bounds.extend(latlng);
    }
    // Finally the bounds variable is used to set the map bounds
    // with fitBounds() function
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}


// This function creates each marker and it sets their Info Window content
function createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NumAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm, OpenAmVen, CloseAmVen, OpenPmVen, ClosePmVen, OpenAmDim, CloseAmDim, OpenPmDim, ClosePmDim, IMEI, Date_Added) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title: CodeClient
  });

  markerArray.push(marker); //push local var marker into global array
  // add marker to the MarkerClusterer
  markerCluster.addMarker(marker);

  // This event expects a click on a marker
  // When this event is fired the Info Window content is created
  // and the Info Window is opened.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    var dicoFrigosDetails = {};


    var HTMLtext = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(dicoFrigosDetails).length / 4; i++) {
      HTMLtext += '';
    }
    // Creating the content to be inserted in the infowindow
    var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
      '<div class="iw_title">Code Client : ' + CodeClient +
      '</div>' + '<div class="iw_content">Précision : ' + PrecisionGPS +
      '<br />Latitude : ' + Latitude +
      '<br />Longitude : ' + Longitude +
      '<br />Route : ' + Route +
      '<br />Secteur : ' + Secteur +
      '<br />Agence : ' + Agence +
      '<br />Code-barres : ' + BarCode +
      '<br />prenom de Client : ' + PrenomClient +
      //'<br />nom Complet de Client : ' + PrenomClient + ' ' + NomClient +
      '<br />Num Adresse : ' + NumAdresse +
      '<br />Téléphone : ' + Tel +
      '<br />Whatsapp : ' + Whatsapp +
      '<br />Nbr Frigos : ' + NbrFrigo + HTMLtext +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin : ' + OpenAm +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin : ' + CloseAm +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi : ' + OpenPm +
      '<br />Fermeture Après-midi : ' + ClosePm +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin Ven : ' + OpenAmVen +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin Ven : ' + CloseAmVen +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi Ven: ' + OpenPmVen +
      '<br />Fermeture après-midi Ven: ' + ClosePmVen +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin Dim : ' + OpenAmDim +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin Dim : ' + CloseAmDim +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi Dim : ' + OpenPmDim +
      '<br />Fermeture après-midi Dim : ' + ClosePmDim +
      '<br />IMEI : ' + IMEI +
      '<br />Date Passage : ' + Date_Added +
      '</div>';

    // including content to the Info Window.
    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
    // opening the Info Window in the current map and at the current marker location.
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

#iw_container .iw_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.iw_content {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>InnoTech - Map - Server</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" />
```