# Marker Clusterer not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement Marker Clusterer in my app. I installed '@google/markerclusterer' in my project and have imported it as shown below. However, I am receiving the error: *core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: _google_markerclusterer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__ is not a constructor*. I have no clue why I am getting this since it should be a constructor. Here is my code.

```
import * as MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclusterer';
```

***Within initMap()***

```
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {

      const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: features[i].content
      });

      const marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: features[i].position,
        icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
      });

      marker2.addListener('click', () => {
        marker2.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        setTimeout(() => {
          marker2.setAnimation(null);
        }, 1000);
        infowindow.open(map, marker2);
      });
      const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker2,
        { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
    }
```

Comment: Try - import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclusterer';
Instead of *

Comment: @MukulSharma I get 2 errors from this: TypeError: marker.getPosition is not a function at at MarkerClusterer.isMarkerInBounds_ and Cannot create property 'isAdded' on string 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/info-i_maps.png'
    at MarkerClusterer.pushMarkerTo_ (markerclusterer.esm.js:429)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering#cdn

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>`
```

Use this and in your function `initMap`

```
const markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typeError. Typescript doesn't know how to locate the typings. Have your tried `@types/markerclustererplus`?

Whenever I install a library I always try to make sure to look for the types. And also, like Google Analytics & Googlemaps can be a pain so adding them to `tsconfig.json` in `src/tsconfig.json` helps:

```
"types": [
  "googlemaps",
  "google.analytics",
  "node"
]
```

And in a `typings.d.ts` file in your project root folder:

```
declare var MarkerClusterer: any;

declare module 'google-maps' {
  export = google.maps;
}
```

Or put it between your

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';

declare var MarkerClusterer: any;

@Component()
```

if you don't want to do the `typings.d.ts` or `src/tsconfig.json`. Try different options. Angular/Typescript is finicky.

Comment: Love this answer... I get no error from the console but the clusters still do not appear on the map

Comment: For why it is not appearing I cannot tell. Have you tried stepping through it using Google Chrome's Sources? Set break points and step through to see if there are values. Here is a possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49301912/4208845

Answer (score 0):

To make the comment from @MukulSharma more prominent. Instead of this

```
import * as MarketClusterer '@google/markerclusterer'
```

do this

```
import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclusterer'
```